# ¿Cómo hacer Where a campo tabla Pivot Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, tablas, pivot

Tengo 2 tablas con sus relaciones muchos a muchos y su tabla pivot.

Necesito consultar un campo de la tabla pivot que se llama `activeo`, si este tiene valor 1, es válido si no, no se debe traer ese dato.

Os pongo el código que utilizo y tablas:

Tabla **citys** campos:

```
id
city
slug
active
```

Tabla **ofertas** campos:

```
id
titulo
precio
```

Tabla Pivot **city_oferta** campos:

```
id
city_id
oferta_id
activeo
```

Mis modelos están así:

Modelo **City**

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'citys';


    // Relacion uno a muchos
        public function populations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Population');
    }
    //Relacion Muchos a Muchos
        public function ofertas(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Oferta')->withPivot('activeo');
        }
}
```

Modelo **Oferta**

```
class Oferta extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ofertas';

    //Relacion Muchos a Muchos
    public function citys(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\City')->withPivot('activeo');;
    }
}
```

Mi consulta es así:

```
$ciudadesConOfertas = City::where ('id' ,'=', $id)        
->whereHas ('activeo', function ($query){ $query->where ('city_oferta.activeo', '=',1);
})->with('ofertas')->get();
```

Necesito averiguar como resolver, el problema de solo tener en mis datos las ofertas que estén con el campo `activeo = 1`, estas como veis las tengo en la tabla pivot.

Esta consulta me da un error *como que la tabla citys, no contiene el campo activeo, es cierto, pero la tabla pivot sí la tiene y de hecho le envío a buscarla ahí, pero no funciona, me da el error citado*.

¿Cómo debería armar la consulta, para que esta fuera efectiva?

Saludos

Comment: El método whereHas es para consultar la existencia de una relación, pero le estás pasando una columna. Cual es el error precisamente? La relación es ofertas, entonces puedes probar `->whereHas ('ofertas', function ($query){ $query->where ('activeo', '=',1);}...`

Comment: Perfecta tu aclaración, no entendía bien como se debía utilizar `whereHas`. Gracias

Comment: Para entendernos... Quieres que la consulta te devuelva la City con las ofertas donde activeo tenga valor 1, y en el caso de que ninguna oferta tenga el activeo en 1, te devuelva la City con las ofertas vacias? O quieres que si no hay ofertas donde activeo tenga valor 1, no te devuelva la City? El whereHas no te va a devolver la City en caso de que la condición no se cumpla. Si aún quieres la City pero solo con las ofertas que cumplan la condición, el where debes ponerlo en el with y quitar el whereHas. Son 2 casos distintos, se entiende?

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar las tablas `pivot` no deberian llevar datos `a parte de id's` en tal caso tendrias que relacionar `city [1] <- [M] oferta_city` y `oferta_city [M] -> [1] oferta`

**Modelo OfertaCity**

```
class OfertaCity extends Model {
    protected $table = 'citys';
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function ciudad(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City',"city_id","id");//puedes jugar invirtiendo el orden de los id's
    }
    public function oferta(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Oferta',"oferta_id","id");//puedes jugar invirtiendo el orden de los id's
    }
}
```

**Modificar modelo City y Oferta**

```
//City
public function ofertacity(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\OfertaCity',"city_id","id");//puedes jugar invirtiendo el orden de los id's
}
//Oferta
public function ofertacity(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\OfertaCity',"city_id","id");//puedes jugar invirtiendo el orden de los id's
}
```

**Consulta**

```
$estado = 1; // en caso de que sera variable
$ciudadesConOfertas = OfertaCity::with("ofertas")
                     ->where ('id', $id)
                     ->where("activeo",$estado)
                     ->get();
```

Pero si tu relacion es `city [M] <-> [M] oferta` y el atributo `activeo` deberia estar en `oferta`

Lo que tienes que filtrar es en el otro modelo, no en la relacion

**Modelos City y Oferta**

```
//City
public function ofertas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Oferta',"city_oferta","oferta_id","id");
}

//Oferta
public function citys(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\City',"city_oferta","city_id","id");
}
```

**Consulta**

```
$estado = 1; // en caso de que sera variable
$ciudadesConOfertas = City::with(["ofertas" => function($query) use ($estado){
    $query->where("activeo",$estado);
}])->find($id);
```

Comment: Ese where se puede sustituir perfecto y creo que hasta sería mejor por findOrFail para que retorne una excepción en caso de no encontrar un valor asociado a ese ID

Comment: Y si la oferta está activa en una ciudad pero no en otra como lo resuelves poniendo `activeo` en oferta?

Comment: en ese caso ya no se trar de un muchos a muchos, si no de una tabla uno a muchos, teniendo como tabla intermedia a `oferta_city`

Answer (score 0):

El método whereHas es para consultar la existencia de una relación, pero le estás pasando una columna. La relación es `ofertas`, entonces puedes usar

```
->whereHas ('ofertas', function ($query) { 
    $query->where ('city_oferta.activeo', '=', 1);
})
```

Usando `whereHas()`, la consulta no te va a devolver la `City` en caso de que la condición no se cumpla.

En cambio, si quieres que la consulta te devuelva la `City` con las ofertas donde activeo tenga valor `1`, y en el caso de que ninguna oferta tenga el `activeo` en `1`, te devuelva la `City` con las `ofertas` vacias, o solo con las `ofertas` que cumplan la condición, el `where()` debes ponerlo en el `with()` y quitar el `whereHas()`.

```
->with([
    'ofertas' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('city_oferta.activeo', '=', 1);
    },
])
```