# ¿Cómo imprimir datos de colección Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una duda y no doy con la instrucción adecuada y hacer lo que quiero.

Tengo 3 modelos con una relación muchos a muchos, ademas tengo su table pivot/e.

Los modelos son:

**Modelo Rama**:

```
class Rama extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'ramas';

    public function servicios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Servicio", 'rama_servicio_tecnico')->withPivot('active_s');
    }

    public function tecnicos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Tecnico", 'rama_servicio_tecnico')->withPivot('active_s');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Servicio**:

```
class Servicio extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'servicios';

    public function tecnicos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Servicio", 'rama_servicio_tecnico')->withPivot('active_s');
        //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Servicio')->withPivot('active_s');
    }

    public function ramas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Rama", 'rama_servicio_tecnico_servicio')->withPivot('active_s');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Tecnico**:

```
class Tecnico extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tecnicos';
    //

    public function servicios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Servicio", 'rama_servicio_tecnico')->withPivot('active_s');
    }

    public function ramas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Rama", 'rama_servicio_tecnico')->withPivot('active_s');
    }
}
```

En el controlador tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$tecnicoRamasServicios = Tecnico::where ('id' ,'=', 1)
    ->whereHas ('ramas', function ($query){ $query->where ('rama_servicio_tecnico.active_s', '=', 1);
    })->with('ramas')->get();
```

Este [tipo de consulta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329633/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-where-a-campo-tabla-pivot-laravel) lo aprendi gracias los participantes de StackOverflow Español.

La consulta esta bien me **devuelve las siguientes colecciones** de Eloquent:

```
foreach ($tecnicoRamasServicios as $tecnico) {

            echo $tecnico;
}
```

> {"id":1,"tecnico":"Marco","surname":"Gomez","phone":"111 111
>   111","ramas":[{"id":1,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Centralitas","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Centralitas","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":1,"active_s":1}},{"id":2,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n
>   de Cuadros","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Cuadros","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":2,"active_s":1}},{"id":1,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n
>   de Centralitas","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Centralitas","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":1,"active_s":1}},{"id":2,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n
>   de Cuadros","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Cuadros","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":2,"active_s":1}}]}

```
foreach ($tecnicoRamasServicios as $tecnico) {

    echo $tecnico->ramas;

}
```

> [{"id":1,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Centralitas","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Centralitas","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":1,"active_s":1}},{"id":2,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n
>   de Cuadros","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Cuadros","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":2,"active_s":1}},{"id":1,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n
>   de Centralitas","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Centralitas","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":1,"active_s":1}},{"id":2,"titulo_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n
>   de Cuadros","descrip_r":"Reparaci\u00f3n de
>   Cuadros","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"rama_id":2,"active_s":1}}]

```
foreach ($tecnicoRamasServicios as $tecnico) {

    echo $tecnico->servicios;

}
```

> [{"id":1,"titulo_s":"Centralitas de Coches","descrip_s":"Centralitas
>   de
>   Coches","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"servicio_id":1,"active_s":1}},{"id":2,"titulo_s":"Centralitas
>   de Autobuses","descrip_s":"Centralitas de
>   Autobuses","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"servicio_id":2,"active_s":1}},{"id":3,"titulo_s":"Cuadros
>   de Coches","descrip_s":"Cuadros de
>   Coches","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"servicio_id":3,"active_s":1}},{"id":4,"titulo_s":"Cuadros
>   de Camiones","descrip_s":"Cuadros de
>   Camiones","pivot":{"tecnico_id":1,"servicio_id":4,"active_s":1}}]

Si intento acceder por ejemplo a `$tecnico->ramas->titulo_r` me da error, no me deja bajar de nivel o imprimir ese nivel u objeto en concreto.

A lo que quiero llegar es a poder imprimir la siguiente estructura:

- Técnico: Marco
- Rama: Reparación de Centralitas.
- Servicio: Centralitas de Coches, Centralitas de Autobuses.
- Rama: Reparación de Cuadros.
- Servicio: Cuadros de Coches, Cuadros de Camiones.

Lo he intentado, con anidamientos de `foreach(){}` de la siguiente manera, pero me imprime duplicados, no puedo crear esa estructura, por ello lo de intentar acceder a cada campo y poder imprimirlo según necesite.

Os muestro como lo hago con los `foreach(){}`, anidados.

**`foreach(){}` anidados:**

```
foreach ($tecnicoRamasServicios as $tecnico) {

    echo $tecnico->tecnico . "-";
    echo $tecnico->surname . "<br>";

}
    foreach ($tecnico->ramas as $rama) {

        echo $rama->titulo_r . "<br>";
    }
    foreach ($tecnico->servicios as $servicio) {
        echo $servicio->titulo_s . "<br>";
    }
```

- Marco-Gomez
- Reparación de Centralitas
- Reparación de Cuadros
- *Reparación de Centralitas* ->duplicado
- *Reparación de Cuadros* -> duplicado
- Centralitas de Coches
- Centralitas de Autobuses
- Cuadros de Coches
- Cuadros de Camiones

Este es mi problema, que me imprime duplicados, ¿cómo puedo evitar esa duplicidad?.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución es generar valores unicos de cada array trabajando con collections
La funcion `unique` remueve duplucados, mientras que `pluck` obtiene los valores solo de la columna solicitada

```
foreach(collect($tecnico->ramas)->unique('titulo_r')->pluck('titulo_r') as $rama) {
    echo $rama
}
```

Comment: Conocía estas funciones las había intentado aplicar, pero sin éxito, mil gracias por tu ayuda. Ahora si me ha quedado mas claro, su utilización y para que. Mi fallo era el omitir el método `collect()`, yo pensaba que al tener ya una colección de Eloquent, esta valía para manejarla y no tenia que llamar al método `collect()`. Gracias de nuevo.