# ¿Como no imprimir dato no deseado bucle foreach{}?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Llevo toda la mañana intentado discriminar o no imprimir un dato que no quiero con un `foreach{}`.

Os muestro mi código:

**Consulta:**

```
$tecnicoRamasServicios = Tecnico::where ('id' ,'=', 1)
    ->whereHas ('ramas', function ($query){ $query->where ('rama_servicio_tecnico.active_s', '=', 1)
     ;})->with('ramas')->get();
```

Aqui los **`foreach`**:

```
    foreach ($tecnicoRamasServicios as $tecnico) {


            echo $tecnico->tecnico . "-";
            echo $tecnico->surname . "<br><br>";

        }    
foreach(collect($tecnico->ramas)->unique('titulo_r') as $rama) {

                echo "rama ".$rama->titulo_r . " <br>";

    foreach(collect($tecnico->servicios)->unique('titulo_s') as $servicio) {

                echo $servicio->titulo_s . "<br><br>";

            }
            }
```

Los `foreachs` me imprimen así los datos:

- Marco-Gomez
- **rama** Reparación de Centralitas
- Centralitas de Coches
- Centralitas de Autobuses
- Cuadros de Coches
- Cuadros de Camiones
- **rama** Reparación de Cuadros
- Centralitas de Coches
- Centralitas de Autobuses
- Cuadros de Coches
- Cuadros de Camiones

Necesito imprimirlos así:

- **rama** Reparación de Centralitas
- Centralitas de Coches
- Centralitas de Autobuses
- **rama** Reparación de Cuadros
- Cuadros de Coches
- Cuadros de Camiones

No soy capaz de aclararme como interactuar con `foreach`, para poder hacerlo.

Aclaro que esto viene de una relación muchos a muchos, `belongsToMany`, en 3 tablas con la tabla pivote, llamada `rama_tecnico_servicio`.

Esta pregunta deriva de esta otra, [¿Cómo imprimir datos de colección Laravel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329923/c%C3%B3mo-imprimir-datos-de-colecci%C3%B3n-laravel)

Saludos y gracias

Comment: puedes hacer algo como esto: `$rama = explode(" ",$rama->titulo_r); ->unique('titulo_s')->where('titulo_s','LIKE','%'.$rama[len($rama)-1].'%');` lo que nos regresaria en primer ejemplo: `Centralitas` en el segundo `Cuadros` y solo devolveria lso que coincidan! con esto

Comment: Hola Bryro, me devuelve el siguiente error, _"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\len()"_. He intentado incorporar tu código asi: **                $rama = explode(" ",$rama->titulo_r);
                   foreach(collect($tecnico->servicios)->unique('titulo_s')
                   ->where('titulo_s','LIKE','%'.$rama[len($rama)-1].'%') as $servicio){**. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la solución en mi caso ha sido, utilizar `explode()`, pego el código y lo explico.

**Consulta:**

```
//consulta para extaer datos de tabla pivot y relaciones muchos a muchos
        $tecnicoRamasServicios = Tecnico::where ('id' ,'=', 1)
            ->whereHas ('ramas', function ($query){ $query->where ('rama_servicio_tecnico.active_s', '=', 1)
         ;})->with('ramas')->get();
```

**Recorro las diferentes colecciones con `foreach{}`:**

```
foreach ($tecnicoRamasServicios as $tecnico) {
            // imprimo los datos del técnico
            echo $tecnico->tecnico . "-";
            echo $tecnico->surname . "<br><br>";

        }
            // En este foreach, anido otro, y hago uso de explode
            foreach(collect($tecnico->ramas)->unique('titulo_r') as $rama) {

                // Imprimo el titulo de las ramas que trabaja este técnico
                echo $rama->titulo_r . " <br><br>";
                // Hago un explode(), para partir la cadena utilizando el espacio, como delimitador
                $rama = explode(" ",$rama->titulo_r);

                // En este foreach ya discrimino si el titulo del servicio contiene el tercer elemento de la cadena = titulo de rama, lo imprimo.
                foreach(collect($tecnico->servicios)->unique('titulo_s') as $servicio){


                        // Aquí se imprime si el titulo del servicio contiene la tercera parte de la cadena del titulo de la rama del técnico
                    if (Str::contains($servicio->titulo_s, $rama[2])){
            echo $servicio->titulo_s . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
                    }
          }
```

Básicamente hago uso de `foreachs`, ademas de [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), también hago uso de [Str::contains()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-contains), este Helper de Laravel, lo que hace es comprobar si el segundo parametro pasado en el helper, esta dentro de la cadena pasada, que es el primer parametro.

```
 if (Str::contains($servicio->titulo_s, $rama[2]))
```

Lo que se explica asi : Str::contains('cadena dada', 'cadena a buscar, dentro de la cadena dada')

Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo, espero que alguien le sea de utilidad.